# Windows Network Policy Server is not logging bad passwords in NPS logs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, passwords, radius

I have an NPS server for RADIUS from an Aruba controller. Accounting and authentication logging is turned on and working, *except* for when the logon fails because of bad password.

**Security Logs**
All authentication attempts are visible on the server in the Security event log.
The Task Category is either Logon or Network Policy Server.
If the category is Network Policy Server, a [reason code](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197464(v=ws.10).aspx) is specified, 8 for bad user name, 7 for bad domain, etc.
The NPS logs also specify the "calling station id" which is the MAC address of the end user device (and the info I want for bad password attempts).

**Bad Passwords**
Bad Password attempts get logged in the Security event log with the Task Category of Logon.
They do not show up in the NPS logs, and the event does *not* list the MAC address.
The event ID of failed logons is 6273; the "reason code" I'm *not* seeing in the logs is 16, user credentials mismatch.

I tested bad password and bad user name from the same device (my phone) using the same controller.

**Connection Request Policies / Network Policies**
I'm figuring the order of logon processing is somehow important, but I don't know where.
We have a single Connection Request Policy to use windows authentication with the Authentication Provider as the Local Computer (this is NOT a Domain Controller).
We have multiple Network Policies and the one applying for wireless is first in the list.

I'm figuring the bad password failed logon is "not making it" to the NPS layer, but why not? Why is bad user name being processed by this layer, but not bad password? What is it about the logons that they are being processed differently? (Isn't the difference just a different return code from the DC?)

edit: After a bit more investigation, there appears to be a 4624 (successful logon) entry in the security event log immediately before 6278 (NPS granting full access) for *successful* connections. So it appears the accounts must pass this initial (network) logon.

However, for "bad user names" I believe these are getting filtered in the Network Policy conditions. Currently (among other things) one of the conditions is the account must be in Domain Users. This is *not true* for bad user names.

Either way, I'm not sure why a bad password attempt wouldn't be processed by NPS since it should be an invalid *constraint* at that point.